# Python/Flask/Jinja url_for formatting

Tags: python, flask

I'm looking to use Flask's url_for to generate URLs for tags - however it appears to be replacing '+' with the entity/url code '%2B'.  This makes for a rather ugly URL, '+' would be much preferred.

So, my question is, how can I use url_for - but have it accept '+' without formatting it to a HTML entity?

Answer (score 0):

flask url_for function calls the werkzeug url_quote function (looking at the source code on github). The url_quote function is defined as:

```
def url_quote(s, charset='utf-8', safe='/:'):
"""URL encode a single string with a given encoding.

:param s: the string to quote.
:param charset: the charset to be used.
:param safe: an optional sequence of safe characters.
"""
if isinstance(s, unicode):
    s = s.encode(charset)
elif not isinstance(s, str):
    s = str(s)
return _quote(s, safe=safe)
```

So may be this is where you can do some changes.